# Mandatory to use XCode SDK 4?

Tags: xcode, ios

Well you know they just released this new XCode 4 version thing...... I am still using version 3.x.x.

Is it mandatory to use XCode 4 for my iPhone apps to be approved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not at all.  You can still build, sign and submit iOS Apps using XCode 3.

Answer (score 1):

No, but it is recommended. You can use XCode 4 with base SDK 4.3 and target an older iOS version.

Answer (score 1):

You can download iOS SDK 4.3 with either Xcode 4 or Xcode 3.2.6 from Apple's iOS developer page. Remember that the Xcode version number is not the SDK version number.

You should always use the latest SDK, even if you're targeting an older iOS version. As I understand it, Apple will sometimes fix bugs in older OS versions. In order to get those fixes, though, you need to use the latest SDK.

Answer (score 0):

unless you don't want to try Git integration you should be fine :) I'm struck with xcode 3.2.5 and shortcuts. And I hate iTunes like toolbar for no reason :(